# Does number of columns in a join table matter or affect performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, derived-table

I have table "BigTable" which has around 80 columns and but I need to generate a "Rank" column which I will make use of it during the update. My query as of now looks like this.

```
UPDATE bt
SET bt.UpdateColumn = CASE WHEN (SomeCondition >= bt.RankField)
                           THEN bt.UpdateColumn + 0.01
                           ELSE bt.UpdateColumn
                       END
FROM (SELECT bt.*,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) AS RankField FROM BigTable bt) bt
     INNER JOIN AnotherTable atbl
        ON bt.Col1 = atbl.Col2
```

Will it be better if I change my code to some thing like this. Does the number of columns in a derived table matter during a join.

```
UPDATE bt
SET bt.UpdateColumn = CASE WHEN (SomeCondition >= bt.RankField)
                           THEN bt.UpdateColumn + 0.01
                           ELSE bt.UpdateColumn
                      END
FROM (SELECT bt.Col1,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) AS RankField FROM BigTable bt) bt
     INNER JOIN AnotherTable atbl
        ON bt.Col1 = atbl.Col2
```

Comment: If you are worried about performance issues then test out whether adding indexes will help. Joining on indexed fields will give significant improvements to performance. Increasing the number of tables you join to will inevitably slow down the result retrieval - that is why, i.m.o. we need to always optimise our joins and our table indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the subquery makes no difference at all.

SQL Server has a good optimizer.  One of the things that the optimizer does is select the columns that it needs from the data pages as soon as it starts loading the page data into working memory.  In fact, SQL Server will often push *expressions* on the columns into this phase as well.

There is no reason to put a subquery like this where one is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry my fault it is not a sub query but a derived table(does that make a difference?). Moreover I need to make use of the Rank Field in my update. In that case is there a better way to do?

Comment: @Prakazz . . . They are the same thing.  Yes, it is exactly the same.  The optimizer is pretty smart.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your DB design is ok as per your requirement.
Hope you are handling your requirement correctly.
These two are most basic things.

Try this, if this query is fast enough then you can think of creating index etc.
BTW, knowing "**somecondition**" is necessary to write correct query.

```
 UPDATE bt
    SET bt.UpdateColumn = bt.UpdateColumn + 0.01                      
    FROM (SELECT bt.Col1,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) AS RankField FROM BigTable bt) bt
         INNER JOIN AnotherTable atbl
            ON bt.Col1 = atbl.Col2   
    where bt.RankField<=SomeCondition
```